# How to I reduce a chain of if statements?

Tags: c++, if-statement, numbers

How to I reduce a chain of if statements in C++?

```
if(x == 3) {
    a = 9876543;
}
if(x == 4) {
    a = 987654;
}
if(x == 5) {
    a = 98765;
}
if(x == 6) {
    a = 9876;
}
if(x == 7) {
    a = 987;
}
if(x == 8) {
    a = 98;
}
if(x == 9) {
    a = 9;
}
```

This is the example code.

Comment: Use a switch/case or an array

Comment: I'm downvoting it because it's a personal coding request. A "think about it for me please". How's it ever going to help anyone else?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Change the question to "How to I reduce a chain of if statements", and it will better apply to the problems of others.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: Yes but then it'll be massively too broad.

Comment: @Abizern The OP has now stated that this is "example code", which makes it likely to be closed on Code Review. Have you read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can generate this value mathematically, by using integer division:

```
long long orig = 9876543000;
long long a = orig / ((long) pow (10, x));
```

EDIT:
As @LogicStuff noted in the comments, it would be much more elegant to subtract 3 from `x`, instead of just multiplying `orig` by another `1000`:

```
long orig = 9876543;
long a = orig / ((long) pow (10, x - 3));
```

Comment: Why not `pow(10, x - 3)` and get rid of the `0`s?

Comment: @LogicStuff I started out with `9876543000`, which has three redundant `0`s. But you're right, just subtracting `3` would be more elegant. I'll edit it in.

Comment: Perhaps OP wanted sequence `9876543210` and didn't include all the code. The first one would be correct then.

Comment: i am using this!!! thank you so much. And because of this i am going to get (5) grade on mathematics

Comment: @MihailMojsoski: You must have quite the sense of accomplishment, attaining a qualification from someone else's idea and someone else's work. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

With an array, you may do:

```
if (3 <= x && x <= 9) {
    const int v[] = {9876543, 987654, 98765, 9876, 987, 98, 9};
    a = v[x - 3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int x = 4;
    int a = 0;
    std::string total;
    for(int i = 9; i > 0 ; --i)
    {
        if(x <= i)
          total += std::to_string(i);
    }
    a = std::stoi(total, nullptr);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/2Cdve1

Answer (score 1):

If the data can be derived, I'd recommend using one of the other answers.
If you realize their are some edge cases that end up making the derivation more complicated, consider a simple look-up table.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

static const std::unordered_multimap<int,int> TABLE
{{3,9876543}
,{4,987654}
,{5,98765}
,{6,9876}
,{7,987}
,{8,98}
,{9,9}};

int XtoA(int x){

    int a{0};
    auto found = TABLE.find(x);
    if (found != TABLE.end()){
        a = found->second;
    }

    return a;
}

int main(){

    std::cout << XtoA(6) << '\n'; //prints: 9876
}
```